# Find File path in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a function in angularJS where I need to get the path of the File while uploading. Here is the code

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (element) {
    $scope.filetemplate = false;
    $scope.spinround2 = true;
    var filename = event.target.files[0].name;
    var filepath = event.target.value;
    }
```

The problem is that I get the filepath as c:/fakepath even I try to retrieve the file from any drive. Can someone give a solution for this.

Comment: Are you trying to upload file ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to upload a file from C drive. Even I tried with different drives.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830307/2815635) answer and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43015592/2815635) to display

Comment: The local file path is not exposed by browsers for obvious security reasons

Comment: Is there any solution for finding the path of uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

The local file path is not exposed by browsers for obvious security reasons.

From the HTML5 Docs:

> For historical reasons, the `value` IDL attribute prefixes the file name with the string `"C:\fakepath\"`. Some legacy user agents actually included the full path (**which was a security vulnerability**). As a result of this, obtaining the file name from the `value` IDL attribute in a backwards-compatible way is non-trivial. The following function extracts the file name in a suitably compatible manner:
>
> ```
> function extractFilename(path) {
>   if (path.substr(0, 12) == "C:\\fakepath\\")
>     return path.substr(12); // modern browser
>   var x;
>   x = path.lastIndexOf('/');
>   if (x >= 0) // Unix-based path
>     return path.substr(x+1);
>   x = path.lastIndexOf('\\');
>   if (x >= 0) // Windows-based path
>     return path.substr(x+1);
>   return path; // just the file name
> }
> ```
>
> This can be used as follows:
>
> ```
> <p><input type=file name=image onchange="updateFilename(this.value)"></p>
> <p>The name of the file you picked is: <span id="filename">(none)</span></p>
> <script>
>  function updateFilename(path) {
>    var name = extractFilename(path);
>    document.getElementById('filename').textContent = name;
>  }
> </script>
> ```
>
> [— HTML Living Standard - The definition of `<input type="file">`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#fakepath-srsly)